# Custom hook for AsyncStorage React-native in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Hey so i want to use custom hook for:

- init data from storage
- save data while changes in state occured
- be able to pass function in value in case

Custom hook code:

```
const useAsyncStorage = (key: string, defValue: []) => {
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<any[]>(defValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
            .then(value => {
                if (value === null) return defValue;
                return JSON.parse(value);
            })
            .then(setStoredValue)
    }, [key, defValue]);

    const setValue = (value: []) => {
        const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
        setStoredValue(valueToStore);
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    }

    return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

example usage code:

`const [budgets, setBudgets] = useAsyncStorage('budgets', []);`

functions that i want to pass for value:

```
function getBudgetExpenses(id: Budget['id']) {
        return expenses.filter((expense: Expense) => expense.budgetId === id);
    }
    function addExpense({ description, amount, budgetId }: { description: string, amount: number, budgetId: number }) {
        setExpenses((prevExpenses: Expense[] | []) => {
            return [...prevExpenses, { id: uuidv4(), description, amount, budgetId }]
        })
    }
```

I tried to change instances and setup for this task but still cant figure out how to bypass type and functionality issues.

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'any[] | ((value: []) => void)'.
  Property 'filter' does not exist on type '(value: []) => void'.ts(2339)
```

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'any[] | ((value: []) => void)' are callable.
    Type 'any[]' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

I really now and did it with js but really cant figure out it with typescript.

Comment: what does the `expenses` declaration look like?

Comment: export interface Expense {
    id: number,
    budgetId: number,
    amount: number,
    description: string
}
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useAsyncStorage('expenses', []);

Comment: Generally speaking, it looks like having that setter accept either a function or an array and manually managing the different behavior is causing issues. If you make the hook generic, the typing will be clearer and any issues you find will be easier to diagnose

Comment: okey i will go for that then and i will try to refactor for pures :) 
just tried to get short on it but as you said i will stick to generic go then ;) 

Thank you :)